# Use fade-in and delay with ng-repeat to display list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to display list items one by one with some delay. For that I managed to do something like this:

```
  $("#dropDownMenu li").each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(1000 * i).fadeIn(100);
});
```

It works good when list is something like

```
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ydbywzx9/)

But it does't work when I use `ng-repeat` in a list, something like this

```
<li ng-repeat="time in msg.time">{{time}}<li>
```

How can I make it work with `ng-repeat`?

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way of animations in angular is by using the `ngAnimate` module and use the `ng-enter` classes:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngAnimate']);
```

Html:

```
<ul>
    <li class="item" ng-repeat="time in msg.time">{{time}}<li>
</ul>
```

In your css:

```
.item.ng-enter {
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    transition: 1s;
    opacity:0;
}
.item.ng-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

For having the timeout of each item to appear, you should take a look at @Slava Utesinov answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since,

> The ngRepeat directive instantiates a template once per item from a
>   collection.

You would have to manually add a `$timeout` delay for each item moving them to a new scope of all items together.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ctrl", function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.allItems = [];
  $scope.items = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth"];

  $timeout(function() {
    $scope.delay();
  }, 1000);

  $scope.delay = function() {
    var dif = $scope.items.length - $scope.allItems.length;
    var currentRow = $scope.allItems.length;
    if (dif > 0) {
      $scope.allItems.push($scope.items[currentRow]);
    }
    if ($scope.items.length > $scope.allItems.length) {
      $timeout(function() {
        $scope.delay();
      }, 1000);
    }
    $scope.$apply();
  }

  $scope.getItems = function() {
    return $scope.allItems;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <ul ng-repeat="item in getItems()">
    <li>{{item}}</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add items one by one with delay via `$timeout`:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
    var items = [
        'First',
        'Second',
        'Third',
        'Fourth',
        'Fifth'
      ];
    
    $scope.items = [];

    function showNext(array, index){
      $timeout(function(x){
        $scope.items.push(x);
        if(++index < array.length)
          showNext(array, index);
      }, 1000, true, array[index])
    }
    
    showNext(items, 0);
      
}])
```

```html
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>

<ul ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'>
  <li ng-repeat='item in items'>{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created Plunkr example with angular animate effect. It works [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/d8SdEfSJlaseGXGtgIU8?p=preview)

You should add ng-animate source into your html according to your angularjs version.

```
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.5.6/angular-animate.js"></script>
```

You can use angular `$timeout` service  with jquery `$.each` function in your angular controller like following.

**// css**

```
.item.ng-enter 
{
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    transition: 1s;
    opacity:0;
}
.item.ng-enter-active 
{
    opacity:1;
}
```

**//html**

```
<li class="item" ng-repeat="time in msg.time">{{time}}<li>
```

**//controller**

```
myApp.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope','$timeout', function($scope,$timeout) {

    $scope.msg = msg = {
         time : []
      };

    $scope.AddItem = function(){
      msg = {
         time : ["option1","option2","option3","option4"]
      }

      $.each(msg.time, function(i){
         $timeout(function(){
            $scope.msg.time.push(msg.time[i]) 
         }, 1000*i);
      })

    }

    $scope.AddItem();



}]);
```

Comment: Though this works I (and hopefully every other angular developer) reject this solution completely. Please use the angular way

Comment: @devqon thanks for your comment. I have updated my answer with ng-animate and $timeOut service. It works in https://plnkr.co/edit/d8SdEfSJlaseGXGtgIU8?p=preview as OP wish